# Conversion of Datetime from server to another server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have SQL Server 2000 in both server. We have imported existing data to new server. And also we use vb application. Now we changing our data to new server. When we run application to retrieve date wise details it shows error

> 'The Conversion of Datetime to varchar is out of range'

And we pass our datetime from application is dd/mm/yy but values get inserted as mm/dd/yyyy. Is there any solution. please. thanks in advance

Comment: Solution would be to use ISO-8601 date format : `YYYYMMDD` - this will work for all and any language and regional settings.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are likely to be English and British English as mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy respectively. 
Open the login properties under security in ssms object explorer on the new server and set it to British English.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the default language of the login running the queries.

Probably is configured in English in the new server and not English (maybe Spanish?) in the old server.